# What is the trace of the second tensor component?

Tags: permutations, operator-theory, tensor-products, tensors, trace

My teacher asks to prove that for any matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}(N, \mathbb{C})$ there is true:
$$
A=\operatorname{tr}_2\left(P_{12} A_2\right)
$$
where $A_{2}=E_{N}\otimes A$ and $P_{12}$ is permutation operator for tensor components:
$$P_{12}A_{2}=A\otimes E_{N}=A_1$$
but I don't understand what is $tr_2$ and there is no any mentions of it in the internet. The teacher only says that it is the trace of the second tensor component, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I have never seen $tr_2$, but perhaps she means the trace of the mode 2 matricization?

Comment: I think it's a partial trace over second subsystem. Still trying to understand how it works.